# Add saved email string to email recipient

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

To save user time when emailing,  user saves there email address in a preferences page that should  pre fill the recipient when email is composed. (or thats what im trying to do) Here is where im stuck, how do I use my saved string to an object for the purpose of pre filling the recipient.

Currently the string does not pre fill the recipient

saves here in preferences page:

```
NSString *savecontents = _emailAddress.text;
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:savecontents forKey:@"saveEmail"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Reads here in mail view presentation

```
- (IBAction)email:(id)sender {

NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] <---------- saved email string
                        stringForKey:@"saveEmail"];



if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {

    MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init]; 
    mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:savedValue]; <------- trying to get string here
    [mail setToRecipients:toRecipients];

    [mail setSubject:@"subject"];
    NSString *emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"text here"] ;
    [mail setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];

    mail.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
    [self presentModalViewController:mail animated:YES];

}
```

tried so far:

```
  NSArray *toRecipients = [NSString stringWithFormat:savedValue];
   [mail setToRecipients:toRecipients];
```

and

```
    NSArray *toRecipients = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",savedValue];
   [mail setToRecipients:toRecipients];
```

and

Google, SO and banging fist on desk

Comment: Please NSlog the `savedValue `. Is it correct ?

Comment: You don't mention what the issue here. The main bit of code you posted is correct (other than ensuring `savedValue` isn't `nil`). The last two little bits of code are definitely wrong though. But the original code is correct. Why are you asking this question? What is happening compared to what you expect to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is this:

```
if (savedValue.length) {
    [mail setToRecipients:@[ savedValue ]];
}
```

This uses modern Objective-C array syntax. This would be the same as:

```
if (savedValue.length) {
    NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:saveValue];
    [mail setToRecipients:toRecipients];
}
```

The code you have you are trying to assign an `NSString` value to an `NSArray` variable.

Also, please don't use `stringWithFormat` unless you actually have a need to format a string.

Comment: Thanks, original code was correct as you said, a clean showed in debugger email adress was not a correct format, typo when testing I guess. Thanks for the tip on the newer syntax and duly noted re string with format